# How to create Kendo controls with security markup

Tags: html, security, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, markup

I am developing a MVC web application and on Razor views I intent to use Kendo controls or Html5 controls and assign the role-based security to the HTML5/Kendo Controls within the tag itself and not in C# code or javascript code. How can one do this?.

I pasted a sample code which is already developed in ASP.net page, but now I need to do it in MVC razor views.

Thanks, 
- Vijaya.

Code is below:

```
<abcd123:Abcd123SecurityContext ID="msc" runat="server" Abcd123Security-Entity="CenterGroup"
    Abcd123Security-AccessLevel="Compose" Abcd123Security-AccessLevelIfQS="Edit" Abcd123Security-QSParameters="GroupID"
    Abcd123Security-ShowMode="PlainText" />
<abcd123:Abcd123SecurityPageAccess ID="mspa" Abcd123Security-AccessLevel="Read" runat="server"
    AbcdTx-QSParameters="GroupID" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three ways off of the top of my head. If you are converting to razor and want to, for example, apply a 'data-attribute' at configuration time then you can set use `HtmlAttribute` for common controls and `ClientTemplate` for controls supporting the method. Also, you could extend the Kenod.Mvc wrappers inside of your own [extension](http://www.telerik.com/forums/define-a-custom-html-kendo-extension-helper) methods adding your security requirements as a property. You could then access your controls similar to:

```
@(Html.MyControl()
    .Name("MyControl")
    .SecurityAccess("Read")
...
)
```

> In complete honesty I would look into the HtmlHelper Class above links to make
>   new extensions to be consumed by Razor HtmlAtrribute

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu().HtmlAttributes(new {data-access-level="Read"})
...
)
```

**ClientTemplate**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Some.Domain.Data.SomeObject>().HtmlAttribute(new {data-grid-attribute='@Model.SomeID'}
   .Name("grdMy")        
   .Columns(columns =>
   {
        columns.Bound(t => t.MyField).Width(65).Title("MyTitle")
            .ClientTemplate("#if(MyField!=null){# <a class='test' href='javascript:void(0)' data-custom-field='#=MyID#' data-custom-field2='#=MyID2#'>#=DisplayText#</span> #} else {##}#")
   }
}
```